# AndroidManifest issue with google analytics plugin for unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-analytics, android-manifest

My problem is that when I pull the manifest file from "google android project" of my unity project and paste it to Assets/Plugins/Android directory in my unity project, my app doesn't start giving an  has stopped working error at launch. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your logcat? It's a litle hard to sujest smoething without more information.

Are you using the latest version of GoogleAnalytics plugin for Unity?

Comment: yeah and I will get it as soon as I can but the problem doesn't stem from google analytics really. Only when I use a custom AndroidManifest.xml in my unity project that i have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using the androidmanifest file in /Temp/StagingArea instead of the one I used in my exported google android project.